# Image URL Redirection to CDN in SPFx Webparts

Tags: spfx, cdn

I am creating a SPFx webpart in which I fetch images from a library and bind them to a carousel. I am doing a `GET` request using REST API

```
/_api/Web/Lists/getbytitle('ListTile')/Items?$select=Image
```

To make the webpart load faster, I want to use the Office 365 CDN capability to rewrite Image URLs to CDN.

Microsoft [States](https://dev.office.com/blogs/general-availability-of-office-365-cdn) that "Image fields in SPList REST API (RenderListDataAsStream) results being rewritten to CDN Urls." It also states that "Use the new property ImageFieldsToTryRewriteToCdnUrls to provide a comma separated list of Fields."

Do you have code sample of how to do this?

Comment: The Office365 CDN approach is still a SharePoint Document Library, and thus slow (response times 200+ms are not uncommon, as can be seen in the PnP Webcast) You can create your own CDN on any HTTPS server and response times will drop tenfold